# Android web view with controls, refresh button and progress bar

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview

How to create functionality for the following requirements in android webView?

1. Next Button - Should be disabled when there is no page to load next.
2. Previous button -  Should be disabled when there is no previous page.
3. Progress bar (Horizontal) - Display the progress when loading a page. (Should be aligned to top or bottom and with control keys.)
4. Refresh button
5. Any other nice to have elements or controls - Share the URL of the current page etc..

Answer (score 0):

There is no component available to meet your requirement, you have to create your own, with the help of recyclerView and ViewPager2, List which contains your URLs, I have described using the diagram. User recyclerView to display a progress bar, and ViewPager2 will use to display the fragment, and the fragment contains the webView.

[image]